# RMATE not working to ssh raspberry pi files to sublime

Tags: ssh

I've followed all the instructions on this site.

https://coderwall.com/p/mioruq/edit-remote-files-with-sublime-text-over-ssh-with-sudo-too

But it is not working. I don't get any errors when I execute `rmate (filename)` but nothing happens.

**What I've done: (EVERY LITTLE DETAIL)**

Gone into terminal. Edited the directory `~/.ssh/config` with `sudo nano ~/.ssh/config` Wrote this in there:

```
Host pi@casparpi.local
  RemoteForward 52698 localhost:52698
```

I SSH to my pi with `ssh pi@casparpi.local` so I assumed this is what I would put as host.

Gone into raspberry pi. Installed rmate with `curl https://raw.github.com/aurora/rmate/master/rmate > rmate`

Moved rmate with `sudo mv rmate /usr/local/bin`

Made it executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rmate`

Opened sublime and tested rmate on Pi with `rmate timer.py` (one of my files I wanted to open in sublime)

Nothing opens in sublime.

Where have I tripped up here?

Comment: try to change localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: any updates on your solutions?